# Differentiate probability max function

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, stochastic-calculus

I have function as following 
$d(a,b):=pr(x-a>max{(y-b,0)})$ where a and b are constant and x and y are random variable.
As this is a max function, it will have kink point hence, will not be deferentiable at all points with respect to a and b.

But from probability class I took, given that a and b are independent, that function can be rewritten as $d(a,b)=pr(x-a>y-b)\cdot pr(x-a>0)$ which looks differentiable.

Can i differentiate any of both functions at any point? Neither can be differentiated?

Is there any way to make that to be differentiated?

Thanks

Comment: Why would $a, b$ be independent? They are constant, being independent has no influence on them.

Comment: Also Its important to understand what we mean by max. We are not looking for the max of cdf, but rather a max of set. $$\{X-a>max(Y-b, 0)\} = \{ X-a > Y-b and X-a>0\} $$ this does not necessarily have a kink. Plus you could differentiate it regardless by simply looking at the derivatives at different bounds.

Comment: Sorry, I meant X and Y are independent. And say if there is no kink, is setting different bound necessary?

Comment: was there any other information given to you?
Your result is only possible if you assume that $X-a>0$.

Otherwise you are just stuck at $$Pr(X-a>max(Y-b,0)) = Pr(X-a>Y-b,X-a>0)$$

Please note that your result is not necessary true, take for example $X\sim U(-1,1)$ and $Y\sim U(-3,3)$. Your identity won't for that case.

Comment: another information is that X and Y are strictly positive, and  bounded. That is all I have now. Do I need to put some assumption to make it differentiable?